# Filtering a TcxTreeList

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Is it possible to have an optional filter in a TcxTreeList and only show the leaves that meet the filter criteria for the column (selectable by the user, like with a grid).

I thought it was possible but I can't seem to find how...

ExpressQuantumTreeList 5.49 on Delphi XE

Comment: You will probably get (better) answers in the DevExpress forums. They are monitored by DevExpress staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in filtering feature for the TcxTreeList. 
I would reiterate the tree on each filter data change and set the node's `Visible` property to false. After that call the `DataChanged` method of TcxTreeList to refresh the display.

I usually work with DevExpress components in Provider Mode. 
I have an internal TList descendant that holds my items. 
In this case I could have 2 lists: TListAllItems and TListFilteredItems.

My TcxTreeList would display the items from TListFilteredItems. 
When the TreeList is first populated both lists would hold the same items.
Whenever I filter my list I would delete/add the items from TListFilteredItems and call `CustomDataController.DataChanged`. Then the filtered-out items would not be displayed, for TListFilteredItems does not contain them.

This would not take much memory, for only the first list TListAllItems  would own the items, while the other would only hold the pointers, and not Free the items upon deletion, or Create them when adding, but just add/delete the item's pointer to the internal TList object.